# Set parameter to function in menu action

Tags: python, pyqt

I have something like this:

```
class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.button_sett()
        self.show()
    def button_sett(self):
        button = QPushButton()
        menu = QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Settings", self.switch_page) 
        menu.addAction("About", self.switch_page)
        button.setMenu(menu)
```

Can I somehow tell a function the `textContent` of an action?

Like this:

```
def switch_page():
    if textContent == "Settings":
    .......
```

Is there a better way? I don't want to write functions like `switch_page_to_settings` and `switch_page_to_about`, because I have more actions on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def button_sett(self):
    button = QPushButton()
    menu = QMenu()

    def action(title):
        menu.addAction(title, lambda: self.switch_page(title))

    action("Settings")
    action("About")

    button.setMenu(menu)

def switch_page(self, title):
    if title == "Settings":
        pass  # TODO
```

The lambda is equivalent to:

```
    def action(title):
        def switch():
            self.switch_page(title)

        menu.addAction(title, switch)
```

Comment: Can you explain me please `lambda`? I know just this: `lambda: arguments: expression` == `def name(arguments): return expression`

Comment: @JohnDoe that's pretty much it, it's a simple way to make a function. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks! But I have another problem. You compare string with ==, but I tried it with `is` but it does not work. If I return string before `if condiditon` I get exactly title variable. What's wrong?

Comment: Google "python is" to find out what it does. You should rarely use it, and this is not one of those cases. Stick to `==`.